# Launch Exe from EC2 usedata and have it run on desktop

Tags: powershell, unity-game-engine, amazon-ec2, process.start

I have an .exe that downloads and unzips a Unity "game" from S3, and then runs it using Process.Start().  This needs to happen when EC2 launches, so I am using Userdata to start the initial .exe.

The problem is that, when launched this way, the "game" runs in the background instead of on the desktop.  I know that, in most cases, that's what you want, but in my case it needs to run with graphics.

So far I've tried configuring Process.Start() with info to say CreateNoWindow = false, and to load a user profile and not shell execute.  I've also tried using powershell Start-Process when launching the initial downloader to tell it to use a normal window.  Neither have worked.

My Userdata:

```
<powershell>
& C:\ProgramData\uvue\downloader\Downloader.exe
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

My downloader (server.exe is the Unity "game" that needs to run on the desktop):

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("Build/server.exe");
info.CreateNoWindow = false;
info.LoadUserProfile = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;

Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

If I look at the task manager I see server.exe running in the background, but there are no Unity logs generated.

Comment: is it because its downloaded and still has the protection to block you runnng things from an untrusted source?

Comment: @BugFinder, I don't think so, because it does run it in the background.  It just doesn't have the desktop context.